# C++ и дизайн HTML

Tags: html, c++, gui, веб-дизайн

Начинаю изучать C++.

В интернете много страниц нашла где рекомендуют кучу разных библиотек для создания GUI, но можно ли сделать дизайн приложения написанного на C++ с помощью HTML???

Если нет, подскажите максимально простые способы, не хочется дополнительно изучать еще Java или иные языки.

Comment: [Дубликат](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17517249/3240681) на enSO.

Comment: А для чего вам делать `GUI` на `html`?) Для этого есть специальные библиотеки к примеру `sfml`, там и дизайн и музыка. Можно пойди дальше и взять Qt или GTK.

Comment: конечно можно. Например, есть такая чудесная библиотека https://sciter.com/

Comment: @Максим   не люблю сторонние библиотеки в виду 100% слива информации и 100% зависимости от библиотеки, даже если это открытый код.

Comment: @KoVadim   а есть возможность вообще без библиотек написать интерфейс дизайна??? Вашу рекомендацию приняла.

Comment: @Liza нет. Вобше, есть, но не в вашем случае)) Я бы посоветовал смотреть в сторону `Qt` или `GTK` так как эти фреймворки очень хорошо поддерживаются миром. Если брать `Qt` то он содержит большое количество библиотек для работы с сетью, графикой, медиа... Почти все есть) Можно еще попробывать пойти в сторону `Boost`, но это явно не для новичков

Comment: @Liza а winapi подходит? Хотя о 100% не понял.

Comment: @Максим Скажите как именно написать без библиотек? Новичком меня сложно назвать, я знаю и пишу свободно на PHP, Java Script, HTML, CSS.

Comment: @Liza , поверте, даже после изучения `С++` несколько лет вы врядтли сможете написать на чистом `с++ GUI`. Смотрите лучше в сторогу `GTK/Qt` ну или хотя бы понимать как это реализованно, попробуйте использовать `sfml`. там за 20-25 строк сможете отрисовать окно с кнопкой) Я уже молчу о том как это будет выглядеть) А помимо того что у вас будет происходить отрисовка `GUI` вам необходимо еще и следить как пользователь взаимодействует с вашим `ПО`.

Comment: Если Вы хотите написать свой собственный GUI совершенно не используя никакие библиотеки, а только чистый C++, подозреваю (но не утверждаю) что кроме C++ вам понадобится еще и ассемблер (чтобы минуя различные API что-то впихнуть в видео-память). На мой взгляд это слишком хардкорно. Если нужна низко-уровневность и минимальная зависимость от сторонних библиотек, я бы посмотрел в сторону WinAPI (но о кросс-платформенности тогда можно забыть)